# __doPostBack is not firing in chrome browser.Working in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net

This javascript function is not firing in Chrome but works in IE. Here `'btnUpdate'` is an ASP button ID.

```
function KeepValues() {
__doPostBack('btnUpdate','');
}
```

I tried many solutions which I got from the web. But can't find a solution. I tried with Linkbutton instead of button control. But I am getting the same result. So please help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're stated that `btnUpdate` is a button server control, use [`UniqueID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_Control_UniqueID) property instead mentioning control ID:

```
function KeepValues() {
   __doPostBack('<%= btnUpdate.UniqueID %>', '');
}
```

If it still not work, add `return false`:

```
function KeepValues() {
   __doPostBack('<%= btnUpdate.UniqueID %>', '');
   return false;
}
```

Unlike literal input controls which can be called directly from their `id` attribute, server controls use different way to generate unique ID which regarded as fully-qualified identifier name of the control, especially when used inside naming container/placeholder.

Reference: [ASP.NET Web Server Control Identification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d04y8ss.aspx)